# Preg_replace with REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace a number in current URL.

However, when I `var_dump($url)` I get NULL, when I `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` I get the actual URL.

Why do I get NULL? And do I use the `preg_replace` correctly?

```
  $page = 2;
  $nextPage = $page + 1;
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $nextUrl = preg_replace('[0-9].html', $nextPage, $url);
```

Comment: How about some nice delimiters for your regex? (..And escaping the dot?)

Comment: What Rizer here's trying to say is: `'#[0-9]\.html#'`.

Comment: You must not have error reporting on. Here's a link on delimiters, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. Your regex is going to take off the extension is that what you expect? Also `\d` = `[0-9]` and you probably want a `+` after it so your numbers can be 10 and greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) incorrectly, because:

- Your pattern must include delimiters
- A dot must be escaped if you want to match a literal dot.

You must be looking to replace a number before `.html`. I'd recommend a look-ahead for this and to capture all final digits before the extension, I'd also use a `+` quantifier to match 1 or more digits:

```
$page = 2;
$nextPage = $page + 1;
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$nextUrl = preg_replace('#[0-9]+(?=\.html)#i', $nextPage, $url);
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tL5gF7/1).

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if the answer proved useful to you.